# Can't pass Truffle test with an uint256 array as event property

Tags: truffle, truffle-test, bignumber

I have this simple test in truffle:

```js
it("should emit the correct Transfer event", async function() {
    await this.contractNFT.multiSafeMint(accounts[0], "CID/metadata.json", 3, {from: accounts[0]});
    const receipt = await this.contractNFT.multiSafeTransfer(accounts[1], [0, 1, 2], {from: accounts[0]});

    expectEvent(receipt, "MultiSafeTransfer", {
        from: accounts[0],
        to: accounts[1],
        tokenIds: [new BN(0), new BN(1), new BN(2)]
    })
})
```

but when I run the test I get this error from the console:

```bash
expected event argument 'tokenIds' to have value 0,1,2 but got 0,1,2
+ expected - actual
```

I'm using `BN` from `@openzeppelin/test-helpers`, I also tried with `BN` from `web3-utils`.